# Chrome web inspector toggle all debugger point at once.

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, web-inspector

Is there any way I can toggle all debugger point on/off or I can bookmark all my debug points at once, in chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the 'Disable breakpoints' arrow in the image on this page:

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging

This will cause Chrome to skip all breakpoints in the application until the toggle is turned back to the 'ON' state.

Answer (score 0):

When you *Inspect Element* in Chrome, in the *Sources* tab, to the right under the *Breakpoints* category, if you right-click in that area, you will find:
*Enable All Breakpoints
Disable All Breakpoints*

and a few more other options.